How to access a component on a frame
I have an application with many forms on it. Each FORM also has a checkbox on it.
I can access the forms by name such as:
Form := Application.FindComponent('frm1') as TForm;
This works fine. I can also access the checkbox on the FORM:
Component := Form.FindComponent('CheckBox');
and can set it:
TCheckBox(Component).Checked := true
This all works.
Each of the forms also contains a FRAME and the frame also has a checkbox on it.
Question:
How can I access the checkbox on the FRAME?
Many things among them:
Form := Application.findComponent('frm1') as TForm;
Component := Form.FindComponent(TestFrame.CheckBox);
No help

I don't think I've ever used .FindComponent.  It's simply not needed most of the time.  If the component is placed at design time, you can directly address it, per the answers from JosephStyons and RemyLebau.  If I place the component at runtime, I would have a variable that refers to it, and use that variable to address the component.  There may be cases where using .FindComponent is the better way to go, but I've yet to encounter those cases.

If the Form is the Owner of the Frame AND you have a Name assigned to the Frame, then Form.FindComponent() will work just fine:
Frame := Form.FindComponent('FrameName') as TFrame;

On the other hand, if you put the Frame onto the Form at design-time, then the Form will have a published data member pointing at the Frame (same with the CheckBox, for that matter, and any other control you place on the Form at design-time).  So just use that data member instead, eg:
Form := Application.FindComponent('frm1') as TMyForm;
Form.CheckBox.Checked := True;
Form.TestFrame.CheckBox.Checked := True;


The first example worked (I was forgetting the 'as TFrame' clause).
The second example doesn't work for me because at run time I don't know TMyForm. All I know is its name.

You don't need the as typecast if you are just going to go through FindComponent() for everything. Like TForm, TFrame is a TComponent descendant and so inherits FindComponent() for searching its owned components.

Is this a standard VCL frame?
Controls in a Frame should be directly accessible from external callers.
For example, if you have a frame "myFrame" with "btnFrameButton" in it, and you want to click that button from an event outside the frame (say, in the form that contains the frame), then you can simply say
myFrame.btnFrameButton.Click;

Is that not working?

I generate forms in bulk offline to suit my project. There may be over 1,000 different forms that I can only access at run-time.
You can see this in operation at:
https://www.seti.net/Neuron%20Lab/3.%20NeuronLab%20Simulator/NeuronLab%20Simulator.php
